# How to Return class with list using LINQ in C#?

Tags: linq

I have one "Profiles" and "Addresses" table Profiles table contain one record of person and Addresses table contains its multiple address.

I want to write LINQ query to return single person record with its multiple address in one Query. So I have created one custom class with "profileId" ,"firstName" and list of address.

I need a output like this please help.

1 (profileId)

Mark (firstName)

------Sanday (address one)

------Stronsay (address two)

------Foula (address three)

```
public class profileDetails
    {
        public int profileIdData { get; set; }
        public string firstNameData { get; set; }
        public List<lstAddress> lstAddressData { get; set; }
    }
   public class lstAddress
    {
        public int addressId { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
    }

    //This is my query
     var result = (from profile in DbContext.Profiles
                      join address in DbContext.Addresses
                      on profile.profileId equals address.addressId
                      select new profileDetails()
                      {
                          profileIdData = profile.profileId,
                          firstNameData = profile.firstName,
                          lstAddressData = new { address.addressId, address.address }.toList()
                      }
                     )
```

Comment: Take a look at [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx#Anchor_1). Or better, navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) method? Something like this:

```
var result = (from profile in DbContext.Profiles
              join address in DbContext.Addresses
              on profile.profileId equals address.addressId).Include("lstAddressData");
```

(the *lstAddressData* name may be incorrect in my example above, it refers to the reference property you want to populate with address items)